# Need Help in Excel formula - Product wise large to small

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

[image]

How to get output in excel thru formula.

Pls. help.

I am trying with excel formula.

Total 5 product quantity list.

Need to arrange highest to lowest wise with product name.

If Duplicate then like (10 , 10 ) then select pro. 2 and pro.3

Need Help in Excel formula - Product wise large to small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following formula, which should work with the version of Excel you are using. Also while exiting the edit mode, you would need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$E$2,MATCH(SMALL(
 IFERROR(RANK($A3:$E3,$A3:$E3)+COLUMN($A$2:$E$2)/1000,""),COLUMNS($G3:G3)),
 IFERROR(RANK($A3:$E3,$A3:$E3)+COLUMN($A$2:$E$2)/1000,""),0)),"")
```

---

Comment: Because of +0.01 without considering the column (for equal values). I guess that's what you get when using miserable sample data.

Comment: hmm, basically it does uses as the indexing that is why i have used `RANK()` and then `COLUMN()/1000`